# I want to sort table name just like sorting fieldlist in table

Tags: php, html, mysql

How can I select multiple table at once?
Here is my code

```
<form action="this.php" method="post">
    <input name="showthis" type="textbox" readonly="readonly" value="first_table" >
    <input name="showthis2" type="textbox" readonly="readonly" value="second_table" >
    <input name="showthis3" type="textbox" readonly="readonly" value="third_table" >
    <input name="showthis4" type="textbox" readonly="readonly" value="fourth_table" >
    <input name="select" type="submit" value="select" >
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['select']))
    {
        $showthis = $_POST['showthis'];
        $showthis2 = $_POST['showthis2'];
        $showthis3 = $_POST['showthis3'];
        $showthis4 = $_POST['showthis4'];

        $doother = mysql_query("SELECT * from $showthis ORDER BY studentinfo") or die (mysql_error());

        $doother2 = mysql_query("SELECT * from $showthis2 ORDER BY studentinfo") or die (mysql_error());

        $doother3 = mysql_query("SELECT * from $showthis3 ORDER BY studentinfo") or die (mysql_error());
        $doother4 = mysql_query("SELECT * from $showthis4 ORDER BY studentinfo") or die (mysql_error());
    }  
 ?>
```

and Idunno what to do next I while-loop this its too many and ilogical I just Don't have any Idea >,< 
 here is what I'am trying to do

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxPTn.jpg

Comment: near 'ORDER BY studentinfo'

Comment: You can only use column names or expressions in `order by`. What is `studentinfo`?